# Converting long/lat coordinates for a selected feature in Mapbox tile GeoJSON such as a road to Unreal Engine x,y coordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, javascript, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

The goal is to be able to download a real-world height map, import it into Unreal as a landscape, then draw roads on that landscape based off the GeoJSON file coordinates for that road.

I use this program to select a tile, create a height map, and download the GeoJSON for that selected tile. https://terrain.justgeektechs.com/#/

Current work in progress but coordinates are not coming out correctly.

Selected tile from above application.

[image]

So, this tile has just one road as it's feature.

GeoJSON long/lat coordinates corresponding to road.

```
[
  {
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [
          -80.28769165277481,
          26.931559068024825
        ],
        [
          -80.28771847486496,
          26.94196560632824
        ]
      ]
    },
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "iso_3166_1": "US",
      "len": 4540,
      "iso_3166_2": "US-FL",
      "class": "secondary",
      "type": "secondary",
      "structure": "none",
      "oneway": "false",
      "name": "Pratt Whitney Rd",
      "name_script": "Latin",
      "shield_text_color": "black",
      "ref": "711",
      "reflen": 3,
      "shield": "default"
    },
    "id": 112027551,
    "layer": {
      "id": "road-secondary-tertiary",
      "type": "line",
      "source": "composite",
      "source-layer": "road",
      "metadata": {
        "mapbox:group": "1444855786460.0557"
      },
      "filter": [
        "all",
        [
          "match",
          [
            "get",
            "class"
          ],
          [
            "secondary",
            "tertiary"
          ],
          true,
          false
        ],
        [
          "match",
          [
            "get",
            "structure"
          ],
          [
            "none",
            "ford"
          ],
          true,
          false
        ],
        [
          "==",
          [
            "geometry-type"
          ],
          "LineString"
        ]
      ],
      "layout": {
        "line-cap": "round",
        "line-join": "round"
      },
      "paint": {
        "line-width": 8.693865073365155,
        "line-color": {
          "r": 1,
          "g": 1,
          "b": 1,
          "a": 1
        }
      }
    },
    "source": "composite",
    "sourceLayer": "road",
    "state": {}
  }

]
```

Sixteen-bit height map for this selected tile

[image]

The height map imports correctly to create a landscape in Unreal. Now my problem is getting the correct UE coordinates to create the road.

What I have so far in blueprints. I am using the new Geo Referencing System in UE 4.27 for the conversion.

https://blueprintue.com/blueprint/mdy1ytsa/

The long/lat pins are the data from the above GeoJSON coordinates

This is the resulting data after trying to convert the GeoJSON coordinates.

road-secondary-tertiary Latitude=26.93155861° Longitude=-80.28768921° Altitude=0.00m

```
long/lat converted to EFEC Cartesian coordinate
x = 959964.491
y = -5608767.070
z = 2871456.565
```

I am not sure why height is not 0 since that is a static value I am providing.

These coordinates do not match up with the height map. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Notes: GeoJSON coordinates are in (WGS 84) datum, with longitude and latitude units of decimal degrees.

Mapbox -- apps are visually rendered in the Web Mercator Projection ([EPSG:3857](https://epsg.org/crs_3857/WGS-84-Pseudo-Mercator.html?))

Mapbox -- to pass data to show on these maps, either as a Marker or GeoJSON layer then that data must be passed as WGS 84 LL.

Unreal Georeferencing System doc.

https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/BuildingWorlds/Georeferencing/

Per doc Unreal supports this conversion as shown in link from doc to http://epsg.io/transform#s_srs=3857&t_srs=4326

Comment: GeoJSON is not EPSG:4326. EPSG:4326 is lat/long, GeoJSON is long/lat (http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/1.3/CRS84)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem.  The solution is a complex blueprint, here is the main part https://blueprintue.com/blueprint/5c_w2ofk/.  It is implemented in this project https://github.com/delebash/UnrealMapboxBridgePlugin if you need further info just post a github issue and I will help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).